# How can I pass a WebM format audio input to Google Speech API

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Developing a react web application which requires a speech recognition programme for which we are using a voice recorder it creates output in WebM format how to use this for google speech API

Thank You

Comment: This question is too vague to get any answers. You have multiple better questions you could ask, like "how do I call google speech API from a react application" or "how can I pass a WebM format audio input to Google Speech API"

Answer (score 0):

Use another recorder that captures OGG/OPUS and falls back to PCM audio when OGG is not supported:

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC